# Animate UIView using Core Animation?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, core-animation

I am having a little trouble getting a UiView to animate properly using core animation. Here is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.view.layer.position]];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(250, self.view.layer.position.y)]]; //I want to move my UIView 250 pts to the right
[animation setDuration:1];
[animation setDelegate:self]; //where self is the view controller of the view I want to animate
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"toggleMenu"]; //where self.view returns the view I want to animate
```

I have also implemented the following delegate method:

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    if(flag)
        [self.view.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(250, 0, 0)]; //set layer to its final position
}
```

I am trying to make it so that the UIView moves 250 points to the right. However, when the animation is triggered, my view starts to move but the animations seems to end before the view moves 250 points to the right, resulting in the UIView 'teleporting' to its final position. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this behavior.

I have also tried using the UIView method `+(void)animateWithDuration:animations:` and this approach works perfectly. However, I am trying to achieve a subtle 'bounce' effect and I'd much rather achieve it using the `setTimingFunction:functionWithControlPoints:` method rather than having multiple callbacks.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: For the bounce you could try using a key frame animation on position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try like this

CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;

```
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

    rotationAnimation.fromValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([view center].x, [view center].y)];
    rotationAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([view center].x+250, [view center].y)];

    rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0+i;
    rotationAnimation.speed = 3.0;

    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0;
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming to move your view, your code should go like this:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.view.layer.position]];
CGPoint p = self.view.layer.position;
p.x += 250;
self.view.layer.position = p;
[animation setDuration:1];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"toggleMenu"];
```

You should really change your view's(layer's) position. Otherwise, your view will stay still at its previous position when your animation removed. That's a difference between `UIView Animation` and `Core Animation`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:view.layer.position]];
CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(200, 300);
view.layer.position = p;
[animation setDuration:0.5f];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[group setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[[view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```